# How can an if statement change a variable, when there's no assignement operator used?

Tags: c++, if-statement, variable-assignment

I have a dynamic queue, so I want to check if the head pointer is pointing to something. So I do this:

```
if (mHeadPtr = NULL)
    return false;
```

The pointer isn't empty (which is also why it does not go into the "return false" line) before this executes, but somehow it is afterwards, and I have no idea why.

If I instead check if the variable is not empty, it works without a problem.

```
if (mHeadPtr != NULL)
    std::cout << "yay!" << std::endl;
else
    return false;
```

How can it be that the if statement changes the variable it's only supposed to read?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, you're looking for `==`

Comment: `==` is for equal checking. Not `=`

Comment: compilers warn about this. Don't ignore warnings and/or get a more recent compiler in case it doesn warn

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Visual Studio 2017 does not

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is an IDE, the compiler is most likely msvc and it does warn: https://godbolt.org/z/3Pd3rsvzf

Comment: MSVC's default warning level is only 3. You should generally change it to 4 in the project properties.

Comment: @ChrisMM This indeed does the trick! Thank you a lot. That setting is under the General Tab of C/C++ in Project Properties if anyone else is wondering

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For comparisions you should use `==` instead of `=`. By using a single `=` you don't compare the value of the variable but assign NULL to it.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but the down-votes are probably because your answer is incomplete (and because the OP's code is often considered to have a typo).   In addition to what you say, the tested result is `NULL`, which always tests as false.

Comment: I don't see how it was incomplete? The question was why it is changing the value instead of comparing it. Essentially said the same thing as the comments did. OP describes in the Text what he expects and what happened so i assumed it _wasn't_ a typo